# Calling Apex function results in a "default(...).this is not a function" error, a similar function works perfectly

Tags: lightning-web-components, imperativeapex

Previous functions I wrote which called Apex classes (see the below) work fine. New ones (one example included) do not, I do not see why. The second call throws the following error in a try/catch: "I.default(...).this is not a function"

JS:

```
import GetVendorReferral from '@salesforce/apex/SendVendorEmailsFromClaimController.GetVendorReferral';
import GetReferralEmail from '@salesforce/apex/SendVendorEmailsFromClaimController.GetReferralEmail';
```

//This works

```
        GetVendorReferral({
            oppId : this.recordId,
            vendorType : this.selectedVendorType
        })
        .then(response => {
            if(response) {
                this.vendorReferralId = response.Id;
                this.referralEmail = response.Referral_Email__c;
            }
            
            
            this.showVendorReferral = true;
            this.showSpinner = false;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.throwToast('error', error.message);
            console.error(error.message);
            this.showSpinner = false;
        })
```

//This does NOT work

```
GetReferralEmail({
        accountId : this.accountId,
        contactId : this.contactId
    })
    .this(response => {
        console.log('response: ' + response); //TODO: Remove
        this.referralEmail = response;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // this.throwToast('error','Failed to retrieve referral email');
        // console.error(error.message);
    })
```

Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static Vendor_Referral__c GetVendorReferral(Id oppId, String vendorType) {
        //....unrelated code. It runs
        List<Vendor_Referral__c> vendorReferrals = [Query];

        if(vendorReferrals.isEmpty()) return null;
        return vendorReferrals[0];
    }


@AuraEnabled
    public static String GetReferralEmail(Id accountId, Id contactId) {
        return '';
    }
```

The context would be the first thing I'd ask about, but this isn't the issue. I can replace the first function with the second and it fails (the first function works when not replaced).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer, but wanted to leave this up in case it frustrates anyone else.

I updated my VS Code LWC Extension to the latest version (55.8), wrote and added an identical Apex method (different name), called that method instead and it worked fine. They are definitely identical (code was copied and renamed).

As a result, either Apex is exceptionally buggy and I just got lucky or the first time you add the import to an LWC JS file it does something in the background that only the latest version manages to do properly.